# Multiple conditions in an IIF Statement

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have a table with the following fields and data:

```
Offense, Year, Month, Count, Amount

 F 2007 January 11 $49,238.00
 F 2007 February 12 $24,000.00
 F 2007 March 31 $55,184.00
 F 2007 April 19 $64,647.00
 F 2007 May 33 $100,010.00
 F 2007 June 16 $59,678.00
 F 2007 July 22 $39,700.00
 F 2007 August 3 $9,000.00
 F 2007 September 4 $75,000.00
 F 2007 October 8 $19,250.00
 F 2007 November 50 $106,153.00
 F 2007 December 26 $80,000.00
```

I have data for years 2007-2014 and designing an SSRS report, and want to use `IIF` statement to return data. Using the following:

```
=IIF(Fields!Year.Value="2007" AND Fields!Month.Value="February", Fields!Count.Value, "n/a")
```

The above does not work, it doesn't return the value of `Count` field, it does return the `n/a`.

I'm looking for the following result.

```
If Year = 2007 and Month = February, Count will = 12
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
=IIF(Fields!Year.Value=2007 AND Fields!Month.Value="February", CSTR(Fields!Count.Value), "n/a")
```

Comment: cqi:

I do not get the count result, it passes to "n/a".

Comment: Can l suggest breaking down the expression to check everything works for example =IIF(Fields!Year.Value="2007" , "Expression correct", "Expression not correct")
=IIF(Fields!Month.Value="February" , "Expression correct", "Expression not correct")

That way you can confirm the data types are correct.  Then try combining the expressions to using the 'AND' keyword as show above